# TSQL - UNPIVOT from Excel imported data

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have an Excel spreadsheet that imports into a table like so:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Col1     Col2            Col3             Col4              Col5        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ref      Name            01-01-2013       02-01-2013        03-01-2013  |
| 1        John            500              550               600         |
| 2        Fred            600              650               400         |
| 3        Paul            700              750               550         |
| 4        Steve           800              850               700         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My goal is to change it to look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ref      Name            Date            Sales                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1        John            01-01-2013      500                            |
| 1        John            02-02-2013      550                            |
| 1        John            03-01-2013      600                            |
| 2        Fred            01-01-2013      600                            |
| .....                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So far I figured out how to use UNPIVOT to get the dates and sales numbers into 1 column but that doesn't solve the problem of breaking the dates out into their own column. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use two separate UNPIVOT queries and then join them. The first unpivot, will convert the row with the `ref` value in `col1`, then the second subquery does an unpivot of the `sales`.  You join the subqueries on the previous column names:

```
select s.col1, 
  s.col2, 
  d.value date,
  s.value sales
from
(
  select col1, col2, col, value
  from yt
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (col3, col4, col5)
  ) un
  where col1 = 'ref'
) d
inner join
(
  select col1, col2, col, value
  from yt
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (col3, col4, col5)
  ) un
  where col1 <> 'ref'
) s
  on d.col = s.col;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beded/10)